# Spark 2.0-2.3 DataSets groupByKey and mapGroups

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I see the correct output of the records when I run locally. However, when I run on a cluster the output is different, and seemingly inconsistent. Even some of the mappedGroup output is correct. Is this an issue with spark Closures? Not sure how best to describe what I am seeing.

It is possible I may not understand mapGroups and that not all values for each group are making it to the recordList variable.

```
case class MyCaseClass (keyValue: int,c2: String,c3: String,c4: Double)

case class NewClass (thing1:String,thing2:String,thing3:String,thing4:String)

case class WorkTodo(myClassRecords: Seq[MyCaseClass]){
    def toNewRecords: Seq[NewClass] = {
    //e.g. work that requires all MyCaseClass.keyValue=1 to be in the list. 
    //This function would create new Java Objects to perform calculations and eventually output a set of NewClass records
}

val processedRecords = ds.as[MyCaseClass].groupByKey(_.keyValue)
      .mapGroups {
      case (v, iter) => {
        var recordList = new ListBuffer[MyCaseClass]
        iter.foreach {x=>
          recordList += MyCaseClass(x.keyValue,x.c2,x.c3,x.c4)
        }

        WorkToDo(recordList).toNewRecords 
      }
    }
```

P.S. Any other solutions that still use a Dataset are welcome :)

Comment: This question would benefit from more details. E.g. _how_  the output on the cluster differs. How does the input differ?